# Using os.OpenFile() instead of net.Listen()

Tags: sockets, unix, go, file-descriptor

I've dived into the call stack of both `os.OpenFile` and `net.Listen` to see if I can make a UNIX domain socket using `os.OpenFile`. Below is my attempt. But, after tracing both call stacks (`os.OpenFile`'s and `net.Listen`'s) I'm still confused. The below code doesn't read from the file, apparently, and stores the data to the filesystem.

1. How can I implement a UNIX domain socket using `os.OpenFile`?
2. What is the purpose of `os.ModeSocket` if it's not to be used with `os.OpenFile` to create a UNIX socket?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    sock, err := os.OpenFile("f.sock", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, os.ModeSocket|os.ModePerm)
    defer sock.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    n, err := sock.WriteString("hello\n")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(n)
    }
    b := make([]byte, 10)
    n, err = sock.Read(b)
    fmt.Println(n)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error reading: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

Comment: `net.Listen("unix", "./my.sock")` perfectly creates `my.sock` in the working directory, whereas `net.Dial("unix", "/path/to/my.sock")` perfectly connects too said socket. While you imho correctly assume that `os.ModeSocket` is intended for low level operations - why make your life harder by using them?

Comment: *Why* do you want to implement it using `OpenFile`, when `Listen`/`Dial` is the provided mechanism for this purpose?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg and @Adrian, it's not that  *want* to use `OpenFile` to generate a socket as much as I *expected* that `OpenFile` would return a socket that I could write to and read from. But, that didn't work. I'm just wondering what the effect of `os.ModeSocket` is in creating the file if it's not to set the flag on a file that the OS uses to determine whether or not that flag is a UNIX domain socket.

Comment: Dig into the source code of `Listen` and `Dial`, respectively,then. It usually is a rather interesting journey.

Comment: Honestly, that's what prompted this question. I dug into the call stacks of both methods, saw no relationship between them (independent `syscall`s), got confused, got on StackOverflow, started talking with @MarkusWMahlberg and co.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No. `OpenFile` is a generalized api for opening file, use `net.Listen("unixpacket", "f.sock")` or `net.Dial("unixpacket", "f.sock")` if you wanna work with unix socket
2. `os.ModeSocket` is just a *nix registered flag for socket fd, use when you want to filter fd types

Comment: As `OpenFile` is a generalized API for opening files, is there a way to use `OpenFile` with `os.ModeSocket` in order to work with a UNIX socket? You can cast my question in the frame of an academic problem requiring you to author a `func Listen(name string)` that depends only on `os` and not on `net`.

Comment: @fuzzybear3965 From an academic approach, one could argue (and I strongly agree), that Unix domain sockets provide network like communications without the necessity of having a network stack involved.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I completely agree. The question remains, then, as to why I need to use `net.Listen` in order to implement a UNIX domain socket since, as you said, UNIX domain sockets provide network-like communications without requiring TCP. I would think I could rely solely on file descriptors and the OS file API implemented in the `os` package in order to implement and use UNIX domain sockets.

Comment: @fuzzybear3965 I get your question. If I may reframe it: let's say I want to write a function that coordinates two other processes. I want to create a socket in a centralised service, and then hand the filename to the processes that will actually use it. How can I write a Go program that reliably creates the socket file in the filesystem, without calling "listen"? Calling Listen seems like a waste of resources because I'm neither going to listen to, nor write to, the socket myself. It's not a hypothetical problem because that's what I'm trying to do right now.

Comment: Chipping in a bit late, here. @DoctorEval If I understand properly then I think you will need to call Listen in order to establish the descriptor in the OS's file descriptor table. However, passing file descriptors between processes using a UDS is a well-established practice which is detailed at https://copyconstruct.medium.com/file-descriptor-transfer-over-unix-domain-sockets-dcbbf5b3b6ec and a Golang code snippet can be found at https://gist.github.com/kirk91/ec25703848172e8f56f671e0e1c73751 . I hope this helps! Let me know if this doesn't help you at all :).